# Check if Specific Key Exists in Json Array

Tags: jquery, json

I an trying to produce a check to determine if a specific key exists in a json array using jQuery. Specifically, if I see this key, I know that that no objects that I want to display on the page were returned from the server.

The simple check that I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
 if (data.hasOwnProperty('Error - No records found in table')) {
  alert('true');
 }
```

The array that is returned from the server looks like this:

```
[{"Error - No records found in table": ""}]
```

**Full Code:**

```
var url = 'https://blahblah.com';
var postData = $('#BranchSpecials').serialize();
var spinnerBig = $('.loadingSpinner');

var getClearanceItems = $.ajax({
 type: 'Post',
 url: url,
 xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
 },
 crossDomain: true,
 data: postData,
 dataType: 'json',
 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
  spinnerBig.show();
 }
});

getClearanceItems.done(function(data, jqXHR) {
 var clearance = $("#clearance");
 spinnerBig.hide();
 clearance.empty();

 if (data.hasOwnProperty('Error - No records found in table')) {
  alert('true');
 }

 var items = [];
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
  items.push('<div class="item-block"><a href="' + url + item.ProdLink + '"><img src="https://blahblah.com/Data/' + item.ProdImage + '" width="104" height="104"/></a><div class="item-meta"><p class="desc"><a href="' + url + item.ProdLink + '">' + item.ProductDesc + '</a></p><p class="itemID">Item #: <a href="' + url + item.ProdLink + '" class="uline">' + item.ProductID + '</a></p></div></div>');
 });

 clearance.append(items.join(''));

 clearance.slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  dots: true,
  appendArrows: $('#controls'),
  prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></button>',
  nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></button>'
 });
});
```

**Question:**
What is wrong with this check?

Comment: try `if (data[0].hasOwnProperty('Error - No records found in table'))`

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the property defined for the array not the object, if the array contains single object then get the first object from array and check

```
if(data[0].hasOwnProperty('Error - No records found in table'))
```

if multiple elements are there then try the other answer using **[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** by ***@AmirPopovich***.

Comment: @dentalhero : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that data is an array and you want to perform the check on the array's items.

Use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in order to determine is **any** object in the array contains a key with the error.

```
var data = [{"Error - No records found in table": ""}];
if (data.some(function(item){ return item.hasOwnProperty('Error - No records found in table') })) {
  alert('true');
 }
```

Comment: I think Pranav's solution is more efficient in this case since I know that I will only have a single object in the error response. I imagine if I don't know how many objects to expect that your solution would be appropriate. Do you agree?

Comment: @dentalhero - I think that if you have a single object, there is no need for an array.